# UITableView with Accessory Type - remember the tick

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

All,

I have a tableview that users tick their city and then the accessory shows and then I store that city as a NSUSerDefault. What is the best way so if they need to change their city again, there last one is still ticked ?

heres my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [alllocationsCity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = (indexPath.row == selectedRow)?UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;


    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self.CityTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [self.CityTableView setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.CityTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:alllocationsCity[indexPath.row] forKey:@"CitySelected"];
    selectedRow = indexPath.row;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking `selectedRow`, why not compare the value stored in `NSUserDefaults` with the cell's title text ? That way, any changing indices in the table cells will be accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Better u can keep one mutable array which holds all the selected city names and save that to defaults for example

read the coments

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     _cities = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"city1",@"city2",@"city3",@"city4", nil];

     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; //initially get all the selected cities
     selecedArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"SEL_CITIES"]]; //store them in an mutable array

 }


  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
   if (nil == cell) {
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    }

   cell.textLabel.text = [_cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   cell.accessoryType  = ([selecedArray containsObject:[_cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone; //set the checkmark based on weather the city name is present or not
   return cell;
}

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath       {

  //update the array based on selection
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark)
  {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    if([selecedArray containsObject:[_cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]])
    {
        [selecedArray removeObject:[_cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [selecedArray addObject:[_cities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
  }

  //update the defaults each time for selection or deselection
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [defaults setObject:selecedArray forKey:@"SEL_CITIES"];
  [defaults synchronize];


}
```

hope this helps u ...